# Gulp http-proxy error

Tags: javascript, gulp, http-proxy

I have this error in my console.

[console throw error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPrra.png)

I don't know whats going on. Do I need to configure something in my xampp?
Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Here's my some of gulp code.

```js
var connect = require('gulp-connect-php');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var browsersync = require('browser-sync');
var reload = browsersync.reload;

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {
    connect.server({ base: 'application', port: 9001, keepalive: true, open: false});
    
    var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});
    
    browsersync({
        notify: false,
        port  : 9000,
        server: {
            baseDir   : 'application',
            
            middleware: function (req, res, next) {
                var url = req.url;

                if (!url.match(/^\/(styles|fonts)\//)) {
                    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:9001' });
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    
    gulp.watch(['./application/assets/img/**/*'], reload);
    gulp.watch("./application/assets/js/**/*.js", ['jshint', 'jscompress', reload]);
    gulp.watch("./application/assets/scss/**/*.scss", ['sass', reload]);
    gulp.watch(['./application/**/*.html'], reload);
    gulp.watch(['./application/**/*.php'], reload);
    return gulp.on('error', notify.onError(function(error) {
            return "Gulp Error: " + error.message;
        }))
    
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve', 'cssMinify', 'imagemin']);
```